# how to set session for a console application?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a c# library for my web application where I am using nhibernate.
The web application has the hibernate.cfg.xml file where I set:

current_session_context_class = web

I am using a nhibernateHelper class and a httpmodule to open and close the session on a per request basis.

I now need to use this library in a console application, what should I set the current_session_context_class value to be now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "thread" option that you can use. That will bind the current session to the thread.

For more on session management in desktop applications:
[What is your session management strategy for NHibernate in desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90530/what-is-your-session-management-strategy-for-nhibernate-in-desktop-applications)

Ayendes MSDN article on NHibernate and desktop applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've used nHibernate for both web and console apps, but never use this particular config setting.

I did some google-ing and found this:
[Contextual Sessions](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-2/1nr4enxv3dpeq/6#2%282E%293%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Contextual_Sessions)

Excerpts:

> Out-of-the-box, NHibernate 2.0.0 comes
>   with several implementations of this
>   interface:
>
> - NHibernate.Context.ManagedWebSessionContext
>     -current sessions are tracked by HttpContext. However, you are
>     responsible to bind and unbind an
>     ISession instance with static methods
>     on this class, it never opens,
>     flushes, or closes an ISession itself.
> - NHibernate.Context.CallSessionContext
>     -current sessions are tracked by CallContext. You are responsible to
>     bind and unbind an ISession instance
>     with static methods of class
>     CurrentSessionContext .
> - NHibernate.Context.ThreadStaticSessionContext
>     -current session is stored in a thread-static variable. This context
>     only supports one session factory. You
>     are responsible to bind and unbind an
>     ISession instance with static methods
>     of class CurrentSessionContext.
> - NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext - analogous to ManagedWebSessionContext above, stores
>     the current session in HttpContext.
>     You are responsible to bind and unbind
>     an ISession instance with static
>     methods of class
>     CurrentSessionContext.
>     .....
>     ...however, there are corresponding
>     short names: **"managed_web", "call",
>     "thread_static", and "web"**,
>     respectively.