# Best ORM for .NET Windows Forms applications?

Tags: .net, winforms, orm

Which one is the best .NET ORM for using in a Windows Forms application?

I like [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate), but it seems that NHibernate is mostly used in web applications.

Comment: I am not sure "Best" can be answered without more information on what that is for you and your environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are your favorite .NET Object Relational Mappers (ORM)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505/what-are-your-favorite-net-object-relational-mappers-orm)

Comment: I use nHibernate in large winforms enterprise applications

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/1378028#1378028 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90530/what-is-your-session-management-strategy-for-nhibernate-in-desktop-applications

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate should work just fine in a forms application. You're storing and retrieving data against a database; it doesn't matter whether you throw that data through a web application, a forms application, write it to a text file, print it out, use it to control a nuclear power plant, whatever.

Comment: Agreed, the ORM and the UI shouldn't even be part of the same equation.  There's no reason NHibernate can't be used here.

Comment: is this still relevant 2021?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Entityspaces http://www.entityspaces.net for over 3 years now.  Easy to use, easy to extend, relatively inexpensive, excellent performance, excellent support, and it is always being improved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to not use NHibernate in a WinForms app. Nothing really ties NHibernate to the web. If you are already comfortable with it and like it, you can continue to use it on the desktop without fear.

If you just want to see your other options, then refer to other SO questions:

[What are your favorite .NET Object Relational Mappers (ORM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505/what-are-your-favorite-net-object-relational-mappers-orm)

[Best Performing ORM for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146087/best-performing-orm-for-net)