# Master-Detail view in combination with ORM, Unit of Work and Repository patterns

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, design-patterns, architecture

I am unsure on how to best implement a master detail view in combination with a ORM.
The application uses WPF with MVVM and displays the grid of all available objects as well as the details of the currently selected object.

The ViewModel of the view is pretty simple, it has:

- An `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items` where `ItemViewModel` is a ViewModel for the domain object that should be displayer in the view. This property is bound to the grid.
- A `ItemViewModel CurrentItem` property that is bound to the grid's `SelectedItem`.
- `ICommand` for "Add new item", "Delete selected item" and "Save changes to selected item".

My application uses NHibernate as its ORM tool but I don't want to leak NHibernate throughout the code base so I abstracted it away using the "Unit of Work" and "Repository" patterns.

The NHibernate specific implementation of these patterns is such that a "Unit of Work" opens a new NHibernate session and transaction at the start and at the end commits the transaction and disposes the session. So, the lifetime of the Unit of Work, the session and the transaction is the same. The Unit of Work has a property `Repository` that is using the same session as the Unit of Work and also has the same lifetime.

This is where it is getting problematic:
I would like to populate the `Items` collection in the constructor of the `MasterDetailViewModel`. Currently, I would need to create a new Unit of Work and populate the collection. To not have long running transactions, the UoW would be disposed directly afterwards, disposing also the underlying session.

Now, when the user wants to save changes to the current item, I would need to open another UoW, retrieve the entity from the database, update it with the current values of the `ItemViewModel`, save it to the database and dispose the UoW.
However, this approach has several important draw backs:

1. My code is littered with `using(var uow = uowFactory.StartNew())`.
2. No optimistic locking is taking place. If someone else would have changed the same item in the database, his change would silently be overwritten.
3. It requires two database hits to update the item instead of one.

This leads me to the conclusion that the implementation of my UoW is flawed.

I thought about changing the implementation so that the relationship between UoW and the Repository is reversed. This would mean that the IoC would inject a Repository into the ViewModel instead of an UnitOfWorkFactory. The Repository now is a functional equivalent of NHibernate's `ISession`. The Repository can start a new UoW which now is identical to a database transaction.
This would go well with my Master/Detail scenario but it doesn't support the notion of a "business transaction" that normally is used as a synonym for Unit of Work, e.g. a logical transaction spanning multiple database transactions and user request.

**The question is: How to best implement the two patterns Unit of Work and Repository to be usable in both scenarios?**

Comment: i have not used the abstractions but i opened a long running session which populates the grids and evicts all items which are not displayed anymore (except a frame around the displayed items) and use transaction.Begin(), transaction.Commit() around each buisiness operation "add new", "change" and the like.

Comment: @Firo: Thanks for re-assuring me that a long running session is a good thing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the place where you start a business transaction doesn't necessarily change its granularity.

Not sure I completely get your example, but I can't see how starting a new UoW in each of the Repository's methods (each time it queries the persistent store) is so much different granularity-wise than starting a new UoW when the MasterDetailViewModel populates its items, and another one each time one of the items is saved.

However, as you suggest I *would* inject the Repository in the ViewModel itself since it seems odd for the UoW to have a Repository property - the UoW doesn't manipulate a Repository directly, it's rather some object that uses the Repository *in the context of* a UoW.

Other than that, I think you pretty much nailed the drawbacks associated with short-lived, fine-grained business transactions. There's not much you can do about it.

There are plenty of other session strategies though. You'll find some suggestions in this [article](http://blog.schuager.com/2009/03/rich-client-nhibernate-session.html).

Also see

[What is your session management strategy for NHibernate in desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90530/what-is-your-session-management-strategy-for-nhibernate-in-desktop-applications)

[What should be the lifetime of an NHibernate session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013467/what-should-be-the-lifetime-of-an-nhibernate-session)